# KVM ERROR Cannot get interface MTU on 'kvmbr0': No such device

Tags: networking, network-interface, kvm, bridge, ifconfig

How do I use `virt-install` to create a basic install?

```
$ cat kvm/install_example 
virt-install \
--name AsteriskNOW \
--ram=2048 \
--vcpus=2 \
--disk pool=default,size=30,bus=virtio,format=qcow2 \
--cdrom /home/thufir/Downloads/AsteriskNow-1013-current-64.iso \
--network bridge=kvmbr0,model=virtio \
--graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0,password=Qwerty1234 \
--boot cdrom,hd,menu=on

$ ./kvm/install_example 
WARNING  No operating system detected, VM performance may suffer. Specify an OS with --os-variant for optimal results.

Starting install...
Allocating 'AsteriskNOW.qcow2'                                       |  30 GB  00:00:00     
ERROR    Cannot get interface MTU on 'kvmbr0': No such device
Removing disk 'AsteriskNOW.qcow2'                                    |    0 B  00:00:00     
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start AsteriskNOW
otherwise, please restart your installation.

$ virsh --connect qemu:///system start AsteriskNOW
error: failed to get domain 'AsteriskNOW'
error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'AsteriskNOW'
```

I need to set up bridging?

```
$ virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes


$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.02429143faf6   no      
virbr0      8000.52540020bae1   yes     virbr0-nic

$ brctl show virbr0
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.52540020bae1   yes     virbr0-nic

$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:91:43:fa:f6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c8:9c:dc:28:86:ca  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xfe700000-fe720000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 11162  bytes 994283 (994.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11162  bytes 994283 (994.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:20:ba:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32  bytes 2988 (2.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68  bytes 6154 (6.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx74da3889c88b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::cde:e1f7:5175:b3c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:da:38:89:c8:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1188126  bytes 1537049311 (1.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 744516  bytes 72479274 (72.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Only the guide seems to assume that I'm using `eth0` when in fact it's `wi-fi`.  How does this change `/etc/network/interfaces`?

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Why you ask questions before man reading? See https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Answer (score 1):

```
ERROR    Cannot get interface MTU on 'kvmbr0': No such device
```

I fixed this by restarting the libvirt daemon:

```
sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
```

For newer distro's use: libvirt.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
--network bridge=kvmbr0,model=virtio \
```

to:

```
--network bridge=virbr0,model=virtio \
```

as you see in your `ifconfig` command output. Bridge should point to existent virtual interface.

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, mine was `virbr0`